# Setup multiple location hierarchies in MAXIMO

Tags: maximo

I am looking for a way to setup multiple location hierarchies in MAXIMO. We have transmission lines and pipe lines, but the same geographical location might have different parent for transmission grid than for the pipeline network. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SYSTEMS in MAXIMO is a logical grouping of locations. In order to have a location to be a child/parent of another, both the locations should belong to a system. Use "Associate Systems with Location" action item available in Location application for this. Within a system, there can be only one top-level location. All other locations within that system should be children of the top-level location.
One location can have more than one parent, but not in the same system. One location can belong to multiple systems and have multiple parents in these systems.
You can have a child location as the parent of its parent, provided the system to which all of these locations belong is "Network".
This way you can have a completely different drill-down by the power transmission system, gas pipeline system and geographical system. That will allow your users to drill-down through the different system-specific hierarchies to the same location.